# Git: Merging two remote branches

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

Newbie question.  I'm using Bitbucket to store my git repositories.  I previously created a new local branch of the master, called branch1. I then would commit my changes to branch1 to bitbucket.  Another developer has been using the master for his changes and I need to now merge them with branch1.

When I do git ls-remote I see:
HEAD
refs/heads/master
refs/heads/branch1

How do I now ensure that locally I've got the master and have merged in my branch1?  Do I need to checkout the master locally, then merge it with branch1?

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nobody else has cloned and use your `branch1`, I would:

```
git checkout branch1
git pull --rebase origin master
```

That would apply what you have done on `branch1` on top of the updated `master` branch (updated from the bitbucket content you just have pulled)

Comment: Thanks.  When I attempted your suggestions, all of my changes to branch1 were overwritten, including new files I had added.  Instead of branch1 appending to master. Any thoughts?  Thanks again.

Comment: @user464180 then try the long version of that command: `git checkout branch1 ; git fetch ; git rebase origin/master`